# Error when attempting to install django-toolkit within a python virtualenv

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, virtualenv

I'm relatively new to Python, extremely new to Django and Heroku, and also rather new to working in the terminal.

I'm attempting to follow the instructions on setting up a Django Heroku project found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django). I'm getting stuck at the following command:

```
pip install django-toolbelt
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.
```

I don't know if any of this is even remotely related to the problem, but these are the things I've tried so far:

- Tried reinstalling the django-toolbelt (just running the command again)
- Tried switching from Postgres.app to the full Mac OSX install

No luck. What am I missing?

EDIT: Per Midimo's suggestion, I tried installing python-dev. This is what happened:

```
(venv)Macbook:[SITE] [USER]$ pip install python-dev
Downloading/unpacking python-dev
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement python-dev
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for python-dev
Storing complete log in /Users/[USER]/.pip/pip.log
```

EDIT 2: And this is what happened when I tried to install libpq-dev...

```
(venv)Macbook:[SITE] [USER]$ pip install libpq-dev
Downloading/unpacking libpq-dev
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement libpq-dev
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for libpq-dev
Storing complete log in /Users/[USER]/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 3):

do you have `python-dev` installed? 
If you did, try installing `libpq-dev`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Midimo! I tried installing python-dev, but it doesn't want to install, either. See the OP for more details. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Before installing django-toolbelt you have to install those following dependencies:

$ sudo apt-get install python-dev python-psycopg2 libpq-dev

And then in the virtualenv:

(myven)trinh@trinh-pc:/path/to/django/project$ pip install django-toolbelt

[Source :](http://iambusychangingtheworld.blogspot.com/2013/10/django-to-install-django-toolbelt.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help, Midimo! My goodness, [installing apt-get on Mavericks looks to be a nightmare](http://www.finkproject.org/download/srcdist.php). Is there a way to install libpq-dev using pip? /goes looking/

Comment: for some reason i though you were using linus/ubuntu download and install PostGre from this page (using .dmg file could be your better choice) http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem: one of the messages was couldn't run pg_config.  Despite fact I had pg_config on my PATH and had restarted terminal to be sure.

My solution was to just run pg_config right before pip install django-toolbelt.

install than ran without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this will help anyone.

I'm working through this on Windows and was having this problem while trying to install django-toolbelt via pip in a virtualenv.

I had to add the entire directory to my PATH and make sure that Program Files was in quotes --

PATH=$PATH:/c/"program files"/postgresql/9.4/bin/

I was trying to get this work for hours so hopefully this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

You need Postgres on you Mac because the django-toolbelt will try to install psycopg2 that won't find the path for the database and will raise the error.

The easiest solution is to install the [Postgres.app](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/) and then add to the .profile file located on your home folder the following and restart or just run the command manually in the terminal:

`export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin`

Now you are ready to install the toolbelt